# Angular 4 routing animation only working on entrance

Tags: javascript, animation, routes, angular

I've got an Angular app where I'm routing between several components within. I've recently started adding animations for this, however the animations are only showing one way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'about',
  templateUrl: '../views/about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../scss/about.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger("aboutAnimate", [
      state('*',
        style({ left: '0' })
      ),
      state('void',
        style({ left: '-100%' })
      ),
      transition(
        "* => void", [
          animate(1000),
          style({ left: '-100%' })
        ]
      ),
      transition(
        "void => *", [
          animate(1000),
          style({ left: '0' })
        ]
      )
    ])
  ],
  host: {
    "[@aboutAnimate]": 'true',
    'style': 'display: block; position: absolute; top: 0;'
  }
})
```

Here's an example component decorator with it's animation configuration, this configuration is shared by several routes (changing the @aboutAnimate to suit). This creates routes that slide in from the left when routed to (under the "void =>" condition) however does not animate when routed away from ("=> void" condition).

I have also used the :enter/:leave shorthands for these conditions with the same result.

The component being routed away from does hang out for the 1000ms as the new one slides in, so it seems to understand that it's being animated as it doesn't just disappear- but no styling whatsoever is applied on leave.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you fix this? I'm having the same issue and every bug on Github refers to previous versions of Angular. Are you using 4.0.1?

Comment: I will check the version when I get back from work- but no I haven't found a solution

Comment: @IgnacioRuiz I am using 4.0.0, apologies for the delay

Comment: Very similar problem here too. Please let us know if you ever found a solution?